# Compare pairs of binomial populations

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, t-test, binomial-distribution, z-test

I have data from smokers people in different countries and through different years. $X_i$ can be viewed as a Bernoulli R.V. where $X_i=1$ if the person smokes and 0 when it does not.

The smokers in a country are then $Y= \sum_i^N{X_i}$, where N is the people living in the country. And this $Y$ follows a Binomial$(N,\mu)$.

So my data is like follows. For example USA in 2013 has 50 smokers out of 120 people and 65 out of 130 in 2014. I have similar data for the rest of countries.

The real smoking rate of a determined country is the probability of a smoker there due to advertisement campaigns, so higher number of smokers in a country may indicate a strong advertisement there.

How can I know if the true smokers global rate has increased from one year to another?

I think I have to compare the Binomials from one year to another with a t-test where the null hypothesis is that $\mu_{2013} = \mu_{2014}$ and the alternative hypothesis $\mu_{2013} < \mu_{2014}$. Once this is done for all countries, if the alternative hypothesis was accepted in majority of cases can I say that the rate has increased?

Comment: Instead of testing country by country, why not aggregate all the countries together and get a global smoker rate (which is what you're looking for anyway) for 2013 and 2014, and do a binomial test of proportions?

Comment: @ilanman If you think the smoking rate differs between countries (and it almost certainly does), and they may change in different ways, would it still make sense to aggregate in that way? Suppose that Luxembourg had 800 participants in the study and the smoking rate stayed roughly constant there, while India had 100 participants in the study and the smoking rate in that sample dropped markedly. Luxembourg's apparent stability would swamp signs of a reduction in India - but I wouldn't want to conclude from this that there was no evidence of a change in global smoking prevalence

Comment: I suppose it depends on how we define global smoking rate. I interpret that as number of smokers / number of people (say of smoking age). I think what you're suggesting is probably a more nuanced approach, but technically its answering a different question.

Comment: So if you have to compare just two countries between them, which test would you use? Because I do not think that a z-test will work well since we cannot assume this two countries follow some Normal distribution... I guess that a chi-squared test would be a better option

Comment: You could build a logistic regression model